# How bind parameters for a prepared query in PDO?

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, pdo

There is a database in MS Access, has it prepared (stored) with the name of **testQuery**:

```
PARAMETERS tour Number;
SELECT * FROM Tours WHERE ID = tour;
```

I am trying to run a query in PHP and pass to tour the parameter as follows:

```
// ..connect
$tour = 1;
$sth = $db->prepare("select * from testQuery");
$sth->bindParam(':tour', $tour, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[07002]: COUNT field incorrect: -3010 [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access]
Too few parameters. Required 1. (SQLExecute [-3010] at ext \ pdo_odbc \ odbc_stmt.c: 254)
```

How to pass parameters to the prepared statement? There is a suspicion that prepared queries are not caused by the command "select", as well as something else.

Comment: I'm not following this 100% (plus I've literally never used MS Access), but are you saying that testQuery is a stored procedure, and you're trying to call it with a parameter? @chris85's answer below is fine if testQuery is a table, but from your post, I'm thinking perhaps it's not a table (Tours is the table).

Comment: Yes, testQuery - saved query (not procedure) and I want to call it with a parameter

Comment: sorry can't really help with MS Access stuff, but from your error message, this might be useful: http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php (there is a user comment on there of 'A quick note in hopes that my pain will save someone else:  Microsoft Access ODBC drivers do not support parameterized queries.' but this was 12 years ago so has probably changed!)

Answer (score 1):

In your current example no parameters would be expected. You need to pass the `where` clause in the query. You just use placeholders where the user input would go. So for example

```
$tour = 1;
$sth = $db->prepare("select * from testQuery WHERE ID = :tour");
$sth->bindParam(':tour', $tour, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Another approach is

```
$tour = 1;
$sth = $db->prepare("select * from testQuery WHERE ID = ?");
$sth->execute(array($tour));
```

You can see more examples on the manual's page, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php.

Comment: This does not work. testQuery - is prepared (stored) a request to the database MS Access. When you run it directly into the database window will appear with a request parameter "tour."

Comment: In your current example there is no reference to `:tour` so it has no reason to being binding. I'm not familiar with how ms-access executes a stored procedure. Maybe this thread would be useful for executing a stored procedure paramterized, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575135/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-in-php-using-sqlsrv-and-style-parameters/31591374#31591374

Comment: @vista1x any luck with that?

Comment: No, it is not working. It seems that such actions are not supported by all ODBC-driver. Thanks for the help!