# I get the exception "The formal parameter "@param1" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, data-warehouse

I get the exception

> "The formal parameter "@param1" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output"

I'm pretty sure I got everything in the correct order.

Is anything wrong with this stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spHello
    @param1 INT, 
    @param2 INT OUT 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET @param2 = @param1 + 2 
    RETURN 1 
END
```

I call it using this:

```
DECLARE @return_value int, @param2out  int 

EXEC @return_value = spHello 1, @param2out  OUTPUT 

SELECT @param2out  as N'@param2' 
SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Comment: Show us the code that's calling the proc and raising the error. The error suggests you've specified `OUTPUT` for `@param1` whereas that can only be done for `@param2` (matching the proc declaration).

Comment: @DanGuzman I edited the original question. Thanks Dan!

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the procedure you think you are calling? Do you have `spHello` in other schemas or databases?

Comment: If you only need to return one value, I would recommend that you use a user-defined function instead of a stored procedure.

Comment: Why do you need to use `RETURN` and `OUTPUT`?

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks correct: [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bdc053b1bf92443dd13b7cc59775a0da).

I guess the problem is with parameter list order. To avoid confusion I would use named parameters:

```
DECLARE @return_value int, @param2out  int;
EXEC @return_value = spHello @param1 = 1, @param2 = @param2out OUTPUT;

SELECT @param2out AS [@param2],
       @return_value AS [Return Value];
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c32b58dcccc0f212aad3e86e6107305c)**

It's a good practice to end each statement with semicolon.