# PHP 7 migration from mssql to sqlsrv question

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv, php-mssql

The old code looks like

```
$stmt = mssql_init('Deletion_Request_Execute');
mssql_bind($stmt, '@Lead_ID',  $lead_id,  SQLVARCHAR, false);
mssql_execute($stmt,false);
mssql_free_statement($stmt);
```

After migration the new code looks like

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($mssql_db, "Deletion_Request_Execute ?", array(&$lead_id));
if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "Deletion_Request_Execute has failed!";
    echo 'Errors:<pre>'; var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());
    //die;
}
```

For some reason it doesn't work. I believe it somehow related to SQLVARCHAR I used to have in mssql_bind? I tried to strval($lead_id) still nothing... Sorry not MSSQL expert...

Comment: You'd be better of using PDO if it is available to you.

Comment: sqlsrv is all I have right now :-(

Comment: `Deletion_Request_Execute` is a stored procedure? Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575135/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-in-php-using-sqlsrv-and-style-parameters/31591374 is relevant

Comment: What are the error details?